# Android, animate a view without affecting inner text

Tags: android, animation

Is it possible to use animation on a view (like Button or TextView ...) and just the container face the animation, in normal case (now) when you animate a scale animation to a button for example, the button's text animate too, but I don't want that.(static text, dynamic button)

Comment: Use two views instead. One will be animated and another will stay there with text.

Answer (score 0):

Overlap one view on another and animate the view behind.